# How to fetch whole row from HTML data through shell script?

Tags: html, linux, bash, xpath, xmllint

I need to fetch whole row from table for that I have taken the table data into HTML format(Please see below data). Now I need to get data for a specific row Ex is suppose I want data for 19.8.2 then **whole ROW** should be fetched from 8/19/19(Branch cut) to 8/23/19(Prod Deploy)--[image]

```
<div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="wrapped confluenceTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 123.0px;" />
            <col style="width: 80.0px;" />
            <col style="width: 138.0px;" />
            <col style="width: 138.0px;" />
            <col style="width: 139.0px;" />
            <col style="width: 126.0px;" />
            <col style="width: 788.0px;" />
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="green">Milestone</td>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="green">Branch Cut</td>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="green">FIT Cert</td>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="green">IAT Cert</td>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="green">UAT Deploy</td>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="green">Prod Deploy</td>
                <td class="highlight-green confluenceTd" colspan="1" data-highlight-colour="green">Key Features</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">19.7.1</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/8/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/9/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/10/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/11/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/12/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                    <p><span style="color: rgb(51,153,102);">MOVE TO 3 WEEK RELEASE CYCLE ON FRIDAYS</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">19.8.1</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/29/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/30/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">7/31/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/1/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/2/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">19.8.2</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/19/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/20/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/21/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/22/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">8/23/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">19.9.1</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">9/9/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">9/10/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">9/11/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">9/12/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">9/13/19</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="confluenceTd">19.10.1</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">9/30/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">10/1/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">10/2/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">10/3/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">10/4/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd"><span>Q1 - Feature Release</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="confluenceTd">19.10.2</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <p>This deployment was canceled due to a dev group directed deployment freeze.</p>
                    <p>Original Dates: Branch: 10/21; FIT: 10/22; IAT: 10/23; UAT: 10/24; Prod: 10/25</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="confluenceTd">19.11.1</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">11/11/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">11/12/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">11/13/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">11/14/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">11/15/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="confluenceTd">19.12.1</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">12/2/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">12/3/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">12/4/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">12/5/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">12/6/19</td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">20.01.1</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1/20/20</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1/21/20</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1/22/20</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1/23/20</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1/24/20</td>
                <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Q2 - Feature Release</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p>** FIT certification delayed 1 day due to Holiday</p>
```

I tried with below script but getting output is only branch cut column date-Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -user -pass --noproxy '*' 'https://confluence.es.com/display/Release+Calendar' | awk ' /<div id="main-content" class="wiki-content">/ {flag=1;next} /        <\\/div>/{flag=0} flag { print }' > page.tmp
xmllint --html -xpath'//table/tbody/tr/td[2]' page.tmp | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}' > branchdates.tmp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to get required `td` and then parent `tr` of that `td`. You can do this with following xpath

To get required `td`

> //table//td[contains(text(), '19.8.2')]

To get parent `tr` of required `td`

> //table//td[contains(text(), '19.8.2')]/parent::tr

Comment: Or shorter: `//tr[contains(td/text(),'19.8.2')]`.